# I want to retreive the values of xml file by giving the path of xml file in the config.properties file

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee

I have the following things -

1. Java class
2. Xml File
3. Config.properties file

I want know to retreive values of the xml file, by giving its path in config.properties file, for example say-

XML File is this -- saved as 1.xml

```
<Root>
<student_name>abc</student_name>
</Root>
```

Config.properties file like this --

```
Student_ID : 201
Student_Name : c:/desktop/1.xml
```

Now, how should I write a simple program in java to retreive the value of xml file student_name(abc) by using the config.properties file.

Please Help!

Comment: Are you using a build system (Maven or Gradle), or compiling the class directly? Are you using any framework like Spring?

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? Did you paste your assignment straight to SO?

Comment: Read your config.properties file, retrieve the xml path and then use java DOM Parser to read the contents of your xml file.. otherwise these kind of questions are not answered here..

Answer (score 0):

First you create a Properties object:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Then you retrieve Student_Name property from this object:

`String xmlFilePath = prop.getProperty("Student_Name")`

Then you create a File object

`File file = new File(xmlFilePath);`

Then you can manipulate this file, for example assign it's content into a String:
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-read-a-string-from-a-file.html

(you can use any external library for this, for example FileUtils)

When you have the file's content as String you can parse the XML, but I don't think it's in the scope of your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
  FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("Properties File Location");
  prop.load(inputStream);  
  File fXmlFile = new File(prop.getProperty("Student_Name"));
  DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
```

You need to Import some packages for which you get error , you should be fine.